# set field to current item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a custom library with documents and workflow for approval process. The problem is I cannot extract **assigned to** field from task list to library's column.

I'm trying to **set field to current item**  but it doesn't work

[image]

Comment: Actually i have a library with workflow and task list related to this workflow. All I need is to get **assigned to** column to the library for better reporting. Could you please describe step by step how can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your "find the list item". 
Every task which is created in the workflow will create a variable at the end of the line. So you have to match the "Field: ID" with the "Value: variable ...". It should be written in ().
Here is a link to a [picture](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_giYkJD4yGB8/THMvjBwGi9I/AAAAAAAAACg/-toKrhuhP2w/s1600/Workflow_HowTo_2.4.jpg) which shows you how to match ID and variable. This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field in your library in my example called "gebucht von" and the task action is "collect data from user". Just to show you how to handle it.

Add in your workflow the list action "set **field** in **current item**". 
Add the field in which you want to use the informations of the task list.
Should looks so:

Set "**gebucht von**" (library field) to  "**task list:asssigned to**"

To get the "**task list:assigned to**" you have to choose so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can able to update the people fields in a workflow but I have selected the "User ID Number". bUT in my case "Find a List Item" condition is different but you can try with "User ID Number" matching.
[image]

Above id reference for how I am using. But in "Find the List Item" just to show you how you can try.